# linkedin javascript API authentication screen not returning in IE11

Tags: javascript, linkedin-jsapi

I have a web application that uses the Linkedin javascript API.

When a user authenticates with Linkedin, the user is able to enter the logon credentials and submit the Linkedin authentication popup page.

Authentication code to open up the Linkedin authentication popup window:

```
try {
  IN.User.authorize(callback);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}
```

After the user submits the details, the popup screen turns white with the text "processing" in the title bar. The popup does not close down and the callback function that is passed into the LinkedIn authorize is never called.

This only happens in IE11, in Chrome and Firefox the logon window closes down, the callback functin is called and the user authenticates fine.

From the console in IE (from the linkedin authentication window) I can see the following error message:

```
Line: 1666
Error: Unable to get property 'authorize' of undefined or null reference
```

line 1666 has the following js code:

```
b.opener.authorize(I,M,B,a);
```

I have tried turning off the Protected mode setting in internet explorer. But I am still getting the same issue.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hans, I am having the exact same issue, did you ever end up finding a solution?